# llibcurl post image failed errorcode 23

Tags: image, post, libcurl

There was an error when I used libcurl to post a picture. Code is below:

```
 int HttpClient::PostFile(const char* url, string filename, char* buffer ,size_t len)
{
    struct curl_slist * headers = NULL;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: Keep-Alive");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Charset: UTF-8");

    struct curl_httppost *post = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *last = NULL;
    curl_formadd(&post,
        &last,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
        CURLFORM_BUFFER, filename,
        CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR,buffer,
        CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH,len,
        CURLFORM_END);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);
    lastErrorCode= curl_easy_perform(curl);
    return lastErrorCode;
}
```

curl_easy_perform return 23.

In Vs2013 command line.

It works and curl_easy_perform return 0. So What cause this problem,How to solve this problem.

I found that when I was in another compilation environment(vs2013 command line), it was ok.But in the production environment(vs2013 Win include Like "stdafx.h"), the problem exists.It needs some configs? or have some limits?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from http://jrgraphix.net/man/C/curl_formadd

```
    /* Add file/contenttype section */
    curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "picture",
                 CURLFORM_FILE, "my-face.jpg",
                 CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/jpeg", CURLFORM_END);
```

Comment: Yeah,I test it.I found that when I was in another compilation environment, it was ok.But in the production environment, the problem still exists.It needs some configs? or have some limits?

Comment: You have to check with your production environment logs then. Add extra logging on the backend if possible.